# How to use ReadBodyPredicateFactory to cache payload data

Tags: spring, cloud, gateway

I have Spring Boot microservice, and sending large payload using swagger. At the server I get only 15000 chars and reset 2000 chars are not read.

How can I use ReadBodyPredicateFactory to cache the body message text?

I am using springcloudgateway and added filters. In the filter in apply method I am trying to read the payload json using

```
  DefaultServerRequest serverRequest = new DefaultServerRequest(exchange);
  body = serverRequest.bodyToMono(String.class).toFuture().get();
```

Sometimes it hangs.

I tried with Flux and then i get only half message 
        Flux body = request.getBody();

```
    body.subscribe(buffer -> {

        try {
            System.out.println("byte count:" + 
           buffer.readableByteCount());
            byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.readableByteCount()];
            buffer.read(bytes);
            DataBufferUtils.release(buffer);
            String bodyString = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            sb.append(bodyString);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

Recently, I needed the similar thing in my application and I've found that it can be achieved by Spring Cloud Gateway built-in caching in [ServerWebExchangeUtils](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/v2.1.4.RELEASE/spring-cloud-gateway-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/support/ServerWebExchangeUtils.java)

Before filters that use request content in some business cases, I created a filter that only forces content caching:

```
@Component
class CachingRequestBodyFilter extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<CachingRequestBodyFilter.Config> {

    public CachingRequestBodyFilter() {
        super(Config.class);
    }

    public GatewayFilter apply(final Config config) {
        return (exchange, chain) -> ServerWebExchangeUtils.cacheRequestBody(exchange,
            (serverHttpRequest) -> chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(serverHttpRequest).build()));
    }

    public static class Config {
    }
}
```

In any of the subsequent filters, we can extract the content of the request body, as below:

```
// some ReadRequestBodyFilter filter

public GatewayFilter apply(final Config config) {
    return (exchange, chain) -> {
        final var cachedBody = new StringBuilder();
        final var cachedBodyAttribute = exchange.getAttribute(CACHED_REQUEST_BODY_ATTR);
        if (!(cachedBodyAttribute instanceof DataBuffer)) {
            // caching gone wrong error handling
        }
        final var dataBuffer = (DataBuffer) cachedBodyAttribute;
        cachedBody.append(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(dataBuffer.asByteBuffer()).toString());
        final var bodyAsJson = cachedBody.toString();

        // some processing

        return chain.filter(exchange);
    };
}
```

Then the gateway configuration would look like this:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - [...]
          filters:
            - CachingRequestBodyFilter
            - ReadRequestBodyFilter
```